# Crashing when casting from Date to NSDate

Tags: ios, swift, time, gmt

I found this outdated question (-> [Swift get server time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31381004/swift-get-server-time)) while looking for a simple way to get the current time.

I've updated the code from (-> [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31398731/8914754)) to the current Swift version and now it looks like this:

```
func serverTimeReturn(completionHandler:@escaping (_ getResDate: NSDate?) -> Void){ 
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url! as URL) {(data, response, error) in
        let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
        if let contentType = httpResponse!.allHeaderFields["Date"] as? String {
            let dFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"
            var serverTime = dFormatter.date(from: contentType)
            completionHandler(serverTime as! NSDate)
        }
    } 
    task.resume()
}
```

---

... calling with ...

```
serverTimeReturn { (getResDate) -> Void in
            var dFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dFormatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.long
            dFormatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.long
            dFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT") as! TimeZone
            var dateGet = dFormatter.string(from: getResDate as! Date)

            print("Formatted Time : \(dateGet)")
}
```

But I still get this error message:

```
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

--> `Thread 3: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=xyz)` while calling `completionHandler(serverTime as! NSDate)`

---

I have no clue how to get rid of this error soo, any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" It means that something is nil. Try to find which one. You use various `!` which are yelling: "Crash if the value is nil".

Comment: I'm pretty sure serverTime must be nil and this is also the reason for the crash!

Comment: You should use https. Note that in Swift 3 or later you should drop NS prefix from NSDate, NSTimeZone and NSURL

Comment: I didn't run your code, but if `serverTime` is nil, and you do `serverTime as! NSDate`, that would cause a crash. Is your dateFormatter wrong? Do you mind printing `contentType` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to you, `serverTime as! NSDate` is reason for fatal error: So you may not be getting string date `contentType` in a date format set by you ("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z").

Set date formate of date formatter, matching with your `contentType` date.

What is result of `contentType`?

Try this and let me know date string

```
if let contentType = httpResponse!.allHeaderFields["Date"] as? String {

        print("contentType - \(contentType)") // What is result of contentType here?
        let dFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"
         // Update here - Use If-let block for NSDate casting and remove "as! NSDate" from completionHandler
        if let serverTime = dFormatter.date(from: contentType) as? NSDate {
           completionHandler(serverTime)
        }
}
```

Following answer may help you, how to handle and work with date formatter (It's in objective-c but help you):

- [Check date format in Objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48421809/check-date-format-in-objective-c/48421873#48421873)

Also, once look at this documents/links:

- [NSDateFormtter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdateformatter) handle format of string dates.
- Here is document by Apple: [Date Formatters](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html)
- Here is list of date formats: [Date Formats](https://www.vsni.co.uk/software/genstat/htmlhelp/spread/DateFormats.htm)

**Edit:**
You date format is fine and working.

[image]

Comment: This is the result it prints out using your code: contentType - `Wed, 24 Jan 2018 14:58:59 GMT` - So my date formatter must be wrong.

Comment: Ok, give me sometime, will provide you exact solution.

Comment: Thanks in advance for your help Krunal!

Comment: Use the locale `"en_US_POSIX"`  and set it to your dateFormatter?

Comment: @Jonas0000 Share your full code for `completionHandler`. Any other operations do you handle in it?

Comment: The completion handler is just able to display the result. In this case just printing it out. No other operations!

Answer (score 0):

After trying many times. I found the solution.
Just add this line of code:

```
let Formatter = DateFormatter()
Formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX") as Locale
Formatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"
```

Enjoy!